# The theme I have installed is not showing the menubar on Firefox alone. Is it a CSS issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The website **** works perfectly on Chrome, but has a major issue on Firefox: the menubar is blank, and the whole page acts as a link.

I am pretty new to this, and looked up CSS validator and Firebug, but could not come to a solution. I had added a custom CSS code via admin panel settings:

`.ct-menu-sidebar-overflow {`
`display: block!important;`
`}`

Just to be sure, I removed this code and tried on Firefox again, but to no avail. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: the `display:table-row` rule applied to `.ct-u-displayTableRow` is causing your issue.

Comment: Also your website takes a lot of time to load, this means that there are some problems with your website. Try minimizing the requests you are sending to the server for resources (css, js and/or image files), try minimizing everything (in kb this time), try using gzip and files minifications (js and css minification ... this last one activate it only when you finish since it wont help during development).

Comment: Thank you for the response @david. Turns out, it was the logo size that was causing the issue..Adding this code to Custom CSS solved the issue: 
.ct-mainNav-logo img{
width: 100%;
}                Also, I am going to look into the other issues you mentioned about loading time. Thank you!